# Get rows of table as columns in second table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

I apologize in advance if this question has been asked before.

I have two tables. Table one has three columns `CustomerID, SequenceNum, Value`, table two has a large amount of columns. I would like to fill in the columns of table two with the values of table one by column, not by row.

An example:

```
------------------------------------
| CustomerID | SequenceNum | Value |
------------------------------------
|      1     |      1      |   A   |
------------------------------------
|      1     |      2      |   B   |
------------------------------------
|      1     |      3      |   C   |
------------------------------------
|      2     |      1      |   Q   |
------------------------------------
|      2     |      2      |   R   |
------------------------------------
|      3     |      1      |   X   |
------------------------------------
```

becomes

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
| CustomerID | PrimaryVal | OtherVal1 | OtherVal2 | OtherVal3 | ... |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|      1     |      A     |     B     |     C     |    NULL   | ... |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|      2     |      Q     |     R     |    NULL   |    NULL   | ... |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|      3     |      X     |    NULL   |    NULL   |    NULL   | ... |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In essence. Each unique `CustomerID` in table one will have a single row in table two. Each `SequenceNum` of a particular `CustomerID` will fill in a column in table two under `PrimaryVal, OtherVal1, OtherVal2, etc.`. A row which has a `SequenceNum` equal to 1 will fill the `PrimaryVal` field, and 2-18 (the maximum sequence length is 18) will fill `OtherVal#`.

The main problem I see is the variable amount of values in a sequence. Some sequences may only contain 1 row, some will fill up all 18 spots, and anything in between.

Any advice on how to solve this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: pivot is your friend my friend...

Comment: @MikeMiller check my recent edit. I don't see how pivot can be used if the sequences may be of variable sizes

Comment: have you tried something like select customerID, Pivoted.* from Customer pivot( Value for sequencenum in (1,2,3,4,5,6, upto 18)) as Pivoted

Comment: @MikeMiller If SequenceNum only goes to 5 on a certain CustomerID, wouldn't that result in an error since 6-18 does not exist?

Comment: I think you'll just get nulls, I'm not in front of SQL box at the moment, try it with a SQLFiddle

Comment: @MikeMiller that worked. If you want to put it as an answer, I'll accept it for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you know that it is 18 columns max, I would take the normal pivot route.

```
select customerID, Pivoted.*
 from Customer
 pivot( Value for sequencenum in (1,2,3,4,5,6, upto 18)) as Pivoted
```

I've been lazy here and not aliased the columns but you can if you need to.

Comment: Agree to use fixed if the columns aren't dynamic. You'll just need to add an aggregate and also escape out the column names, i.e.  `pivot( Max(Value) for sequencenum in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6] ... ))`

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a Dynamic Pivot. The first `STUFF` Select (or any other [`GROUP_CONCAT` hack](https://stackoverflow.com/q/451415/314291)) is used to determine the columns needed (based on the values of `SequenceNum`) before applying this into a dynamic pivot which then assigns the values to these columns.

You'll need to take an opinion on an aggregate during the pivot (I've used `Min`), although if there aren't duplicate `CustomerId, SequenceNum` tuples, this is a fairly arbitrary choice:

```
DECLARE 
  @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
  @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(SequenceNum) 
            FROM Table1
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'');

set @query = N'SELECT CustomerID, ' + @cols + N' from
            Table1 
            pivot 
            (
                min(Value)
                for SequenceNum in (' + @cols + N')
            ) p ';
 execute(@query);
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d583e/1)